# getElementsByClassName() not finding element in Firefox 25

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, onload, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox 24, [Devtools-tweaks](https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks) makes selected items in Firefox inspector outlined in darker blue, so they are more visible. In Firefox 25 beta, however, it says it's undefined when looking for the panel with 'iframe-ruleview' class (The right listing of the inspector), although I can see this element in DOM inspector, it is the right panel with css properties.

The relevant code in content/inspectorTweaks.js:

```
// window.inspector is documented in inspector-panel.js
// .doc and window is inspector.xul window.
window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    var frame = document.getElementsByClassName('iframe-ruleview')[0];
    if (!frame.contentWindow.location.href.contains('cssruleview.xul')) {
        //Not the xul, it's a html we have to extend from here (Firefox 22+)
        frame.setAttribute('context',"dtCSSContext");
    }
    function styleit() {
        var frame = document.getElementById('markup-box').children[0];
        var doc = frame.contentDocument;
        var style= doc.createElement('style');
        style.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(
        '.theme-selected { border:1px solid blue; padding:1px; margin-left:-2px; border-radius:3px;}'+
        '.theme-twisty:not([open]) {top:5px; left:5px;}'
        ));
        doc.body.appendChild(style);//what's the equivalent for old xul file?
    }
    styleit();
    window.inspector.on("markuploaded", styleit);
    frame.addEventListener('load',styleit);
    //frame.contentWindow.addEventListener('load',styleit);
});
```

It says `frame` is undefined, an exception which keeps the rest of this code from working.

I tried changing it with the example below, but I think it's meant to open devtools from the main frame?

```
window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    let {ConsoleUtils, gDevTools} = Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/devtools/gDevTools.jsm", {});
    let {devtools} = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {});
    let TargetFactory = devtools.TargetFactory;
    console.log('tf:')
    console.log(TargetFactory)
    console.log(devtools)
    let target = TargetFactory.forTab(gBrowser.selectedTab);
```

^ This code gives gBrowser not defined error.

Comment: Try `var frame = document.querySelector('.iframe-ruleview');`

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML.  If there is an object in the current frame with a class of `iframe-ruleview` then it would work so there's something else going on and we'd need to see the HTML to offer you help on what else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the 'load' won't do, but it is available in the 'pageshow' event.
Maybe the order/event binding was changed in 25.

Answer (score 2):

The panels are not created until the toolbox is open. We have created useful methods for obtaining objects within these panels. I am not sure how you want to attach the code but here is an example of how to open the inspector panel and add your tweaks:

```
let {ConsoleUtils, gDevTools} = Cu.import("resource:///modules/devtools/gDevTools.jsm", {});
let {devtools} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {});
let TargetFactory = devtools.TargetFactory;
let target = TargetFactory.forTab(gBrowser.selectedTab);

gDevTools.showToolbox(target, "inspector").then(function(toolbox) {
  inspector = toolbox.getCurrentPanel();
  let doc = inspector._markupFrame.contentDocument;
  let style = doc.createElement('style');
  style.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(
    '.theme-selected { border:1px solid blue; padding:1px; margin-left:-2px; border-radius:3px;}'+
    '.theme-twisty:not([open]) {top:5px; left:5px;}'
  ));
  doc.body.appendChild(style);
});
```

I suspect that instead of opening the panel you may prefer to listen for the toolbox opening but I assume that you have that in hand.

As a side not, we will soon be making it way easier to create DevTools themes so that you won't need to use hacks like this.

Comment: Thanks, is this documented anywhere? Is this compatible with the last few Firefox versions?

Comment: Not at the moment as our tools are evolving at a very rapid pace. I would say that the best place to learn about how to open and access the tools is in their tests.  

So for example, to see how the tests access the markup view download the source and look at the tests under browser/devtools/markupview/test. Note that tests usually load head.js by default and that this file contains a bunch of helper functions.

Comment: Thanks, where do I find/run those tests?

Comment: Wouldn't that open the inspector? I changed 'load' to 'pageshow' and it seems to work in 25, though it still gives some 'frame' var not defined errors.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this UI in a Firefox nightly, the `<iframe class='iframe-ruleview'>` is inside another `<iframe id="toolbox-panel-iframe-inspector" class="toolbox-panel-iframe">`, which is itself inside an `<iframe class="devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe">` which is itself anonymous content inside the tabbrowser binding.

You should make sure two things are true:

1)  Your code is running inside the `<iframe id="toolbox-panel-iframe-inspector" class="toolbox-panel-iframe">`.

2)  Your code is not running before the ruleview iframe is created, if that creation happens asynchronously.

Comment: In 25, I see it as an iframe directly within chrome://browser/content/devtools/inspector/inspector.xul, which is the frame I'm overlaying. What's the best way to wait for iframe-ruleview element to be created?

Comment: @NoBugs See Mike Ratcliffe's answer?  He's the one who actually knows this code.  ;)